# spring-integration jms selector-expression

Tags: jms, spring-integration

it seems that selector-expression is not supported for a message-driven-channel-adapter.

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
            selector-expression="workerGroup = '@environment.getDeploymentEnvironment().toString()'"
            concurrent-consumers="1" 
            transaction-manager="transactionManager"
            destination="queue" channel="channel"/>
```

==>

```
'selector-expression' is not allowed to appear in element 'int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter'
```

any hints on how i could make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are trying to use SpEL to build your message selector.

The selector must be defined during initialization.

Spring Integration `...-expression` attributes are for when expressions are evaluated at runtime (usually against the message), not statically during initialization time, normal Spring `#{...}` SpEL is used for that.

You should be able to use...

```
selector-expression="workerGroup = #{environment.getDeploymentEnvironment().toString()}"
```

...to set up this selector during initialization time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess instead of **selector-expression** they have added **selector** for **message-driven-channel-adapter**. I haven't tried it, but I guess it works the same as per provided documentation.